# Sum of the two lowest positive numbers in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, sum

I made a function `sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers()` that takes an integer vector (containing only positive values) and it returns the sum of the two lowest positive numbers stored in that vector. Unfortunately, my function fails for a few test cases (I do not have access to the inputs of those test cases). Please help me find the error in my code.
***NOTE: Vector always consists of a minimum of 4 positive values***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers (vector<int> numbers)
{
  long int sum = 0;
  long int min1 = numbers[0];
  int position;
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){ 
    if (numbers[i] < min1){
      min1 = numbers[i];
      position = i;
    }
  }
  numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + position - 1);
  long int min2 = numbers[0];
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){ 
    if (numbers[i] < min2){
      min2 = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  sum = min1 + min2;
  return sum;
}
```

**Logic:**
I have tried to first find the smallest value and store it in a variable and then remove that value from the vector. After that, I again searched for the smallest value in the vector and stored it in a variable. In end, I have added the two values and returned the sum.

Comment: You don't initialize `position` before the first loop, so if the 0th number happens to be the smallest, you use that uninitialized value in your erase instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of issues:

1. If the smallest number in the `vector` is the first, `position` will be uninitialized and cause UB (Undefined Behavior).
2. If you'll initiazlie `position` to 0 as required, then again if the smallest number in the `vector` is the first, this line `numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + position - 1)` will attempt to use an iterator to **before** numbers.begin(). This is invalid.

My solution below only keeps track of `smallest` and `secondSmallest` without having to modify the `vector` at all (and thus I can pass it by `const&`). It also requires only one traverse of the `vector` (and the complexity is O(n)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

long sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers(std::vector<int> const & numbers)
{
    assert(numbers.size() >= 4);   // The OP specified that in the question.
    int smallest =       (numbers[0] < numbers[1]) ? numbers[0] : numbers[1];
    int secondSmallest = (numbers[0] < numbers[1]) ? numbers[1] : numbers[0];
    for (size_t i = 2; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < smallest)
        {
            // Need to update both:
            secondSmallest = smallest;
            smallest = numbers[i];
        }
        else if (numbers[i] < secondSmallest)
        {
            // Need to update only second:
            secondSmallest = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return (smallest + secondSmallest);

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,4,7,2 };
    auto s = sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers(v);
    std::cout << "sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers: " << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers: 3
```

A side note: it's better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this:

```
// Simple function that will swap smallest with next_smallest
// if smallest > next_smallest. Returns true if a swap happened
bool TwoItemSort(int& smallest, int& next_smallest)
{
    if (next_smallest < smallest)
    {
        int tmp = smallest;
        smallest = next_smallest;
        next_smallest = tmp;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

long sumOfTwoSmallestNumbers(const vector<int>& numbers)
{
    if (numbers.size() < 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int smallest = numbers[0];
    int nextsmallest = numbers[1];

    TwoItemSort(smallest, nextsmallest);

    for (size_t i = 2; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        int value = numbers[i];
        if (TwoItemSort(nextsmallest, value))
        {
            TwoItemSort(smallest, nextsmallest);
        }
    }

    return smallest + nextsmallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

um, this is a two-liner...

```c++
std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
auto sum = vec.at(0) + vec.at(1);
```

---

Hope this helps

---

Caveat: it does not skip negative numbers, but that has been left out as a learning exercise for the OP.

Comment: That runs in `O(n lg n)` time. Can you make it faster such that it runs in `O(n)` time?

Comment: Also helpful to point out what went wrong with the asker's version.

Comment: @selbie, why do you think it take O(n lg n) time? If I recall correctly, the time complexity of std::sort is undefined. Also, my code will work on a more generalized case too, where the sum of first 'n' smallest numbers is asked.

Comment: [Complexity of `std::sort` is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Complexity). It's not possible to sort in much less than nlog(n) without a lot of caveats and controls.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int sumOfSmallestPositive(vector<int> arr);

int main()
{

     vector<int> arr{-8,-24,14,-56,-1,5,87,12,-10,11};
     cout<<sumOfSmallestPositive(arr);
     return 0;
}


int sumOfSmallestPositive(vector<int> arr)
{
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    pair<int,int> p;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>0)
        {
            p.first=arr[i];
            p.second=0;
            if(i+1<=arr.size()-1)
                p.second=arr[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return p.first +p.second;  //return 5+11=16
}
```

Comment: 1. please do not use `using namespace std` and `bits`. Secondly, you already have the sorted array in `sort()`. Why would you require the succeeding for loop?

Comment: The array may have many negative elements and we only have to find the sum of two smallest positive numbers that is why we used a loop here to find out the small positive elements of array

Comment: If we dont want to use bits library what we can simply do is, instead of using vector just use integer array and pass in function and secondly instead of using sort(arr.begin(),arr.end()) use sort(arr,arr+n).

Comment: no, it's fine to use the vector. Just never ever use bits.